# ClueMapper for multiple project tracking

Tags: project-management, bug-tracking

I currently have several projects in separate SVN repositories and across multiple Trac installations. I'd like to combine them all into one project management/issue tracking setup. From the looks of it, Trac doesn't handle multiple projects well. I considered using Redmine after reading [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/674505/looking-for-an-alternative-to-trac-project-management-and-bug-tracking-system-fo) but I'd rather stay with Trac if I can.

**Has anyone used ClueMapper? Is it good? Is it actively developed? How different is it from Trac? How hard is it to set up?**

If you have any other suggestions for projects

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Guess no one uses ClueMapper. I wound up going with Redmine and it's way better than Trac. I highly recommend it.